# How to appendChild to a react component in the correct place within a jest test DOM

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a react component consisting of a wrapper div and a checkbox inside, here is the render function:

```
render: function(){
    return (
        <div id="wrapperDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

On `componentDidMount` I swap out this checkbox for a div that will act as the checkbox, here is the `componentDidMount` function;

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "checkboxDiv";
    this.getDOMNode().appendChild(div);
}
```

when rendering this on screen the empty div is added to the component and all works fine.

On my jest test I try this;

```
TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, "div");
```

But the length of this array is 1, bringing back only the div with the id of "wrapperDiv" looking as though it has not added the checkboxDiv to the DOM. However when I try this in the test;

```
component.getDOMNode().parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

It brings back the `wrapperDiv` and the `checkboxDiv`

Is there a reason it doesn't add the div in the component, or is there an extra step needed in the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag()` only looks at Reacts internal render tree. And since you're adding the DOM node without React knowing about it, the DOM node won't show up in Reacts render tree.

Comment: Ah right ok that would make sense. Is there any way I could add it to the internal render tree when the component is mounted that you know of?

Comment: No, because when you work with the DOM directly, you're no longer working with Reacts virtual DOM, which is what Reacts render tree is made up of. If you're looking for a real DOM node, you're better off using the native DOM API's like `getElementsByTagName`.